# How to execute automation scripts in IE & Edge browser InPrivate mode using selenium c#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#, ie

I hardly tried to open InPrivate mode in IE and Edge browser using Selenium C#. Below code for IE11 Windows 8 but doesn't work for me:

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions(); 
options.ForceCreateProcessApi = true; 
options.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private"; 

IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has changed the behavior of IE11, and broken the IE driver in the process.
The problem is with the browser's behavior change. There is no clear-cut workaround yet. You could try setting the initialBrowserUrl capability via the InternetExplorerOptions
class, but there's no guarantee that it will work.

```
InternetExplorerDriverService ieDriverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(webDriverDir);

ieDriverService.LoggingLevel = InternetExplorerDriverLogLevel.Trace;   
ieDriverService.LogFile = "c:\\jenkins\\iedriver.log";

var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";

return new InternetExplorerDriver(ieDriverService, ieOptions);
```

Comment: @ Bharat Thanks. I have tried that way but does not work. 
InternetExplorerDriver does not contain a definition for "FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS". Same for "IE_SWITCHES".

Comment: Currently, I'm using IE-10 version and it's working on my PC. You have to check some changes for IE-11.

Comment: Ha, we've been searching all day yesterday why IE11 tests wouldn't run for someone with a higher IE11 build than me. Where did you get this information?

Comment: This issue was already raised by someone on Github. You may search BUG-ID-#6511 & #6544 on Github. You can check on GitHub it will be great if you found any updates on this. 
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6511

Comment: Yup....Thanks for the info. I have been facing this issue from last 3/4 months. When we get the update on this??